# Who got buried alive according to Cletus Kasady?

Tags: venom

In *Venom Let There Be Carnage* (2021), Cletus Kasady meets Venom:

> Cletus Kasady: **Do a man who's buried alive a kindness**, won't you? Get
> a message out to all my...fans. And in return, I'll give you my
> life......story. I heard the written word hasn't been working out so
> well.

Who got buried alive according to Cletus Kasady?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on English Language Learners. It’s nothing to do with understanding the fictional work; it’s to do with understanding English.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - while questions like these would _most likely_ be better received on ELL, they are [on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11626) here if the work is on-topic

Comment: @fez Yes, it's in scope for this community.

Comment: @fez I think it's a completely wrongheaded policy, but I have duly voted in accordance with it anyway. :-P

Comment: @DavidW same here honestly

Comment: Cool cool — sorry, I’d missed that this has already been decided. I can see it both ways, happy to go with the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cletus is referring to *himself* as the man who's 'buried alive'.

Mr Kasady is imprisoned on Death Row at [San Quentin Prison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWD5L.jpg), presumably in Cell Block "B" which is reserved for prisoners who can't play nice with other prisoners or otherwise show a poor attitude to imprisonment.

This block is colloquially known as '***the hole***' and those that are required to stay long-term are often referred to as being '[*buried alive*](https://www.counterpunch.org/2007/09/04/buried-alive-on-san-quentin-s-death-row/)'

> During confinement a prisoner constantly faces the potential of
> getting into trouble with the staff or with fellow prisoners.
> Troublesome prisoners at san quentin may be subjected to the routine
> of the adjustment center (AC) or B section, which is commonly known as
> 'the hole.' the AC is a prison within a prison; a prisoner will be
> kept in ac for at least the major portion of a year, if not for
> several years. Upon entry into the AC, a prisoner is usually put in
> isolation. Although legally a prisoner cannot be kept in isolation for
> more than 29 days, there are a number of ways the staff can circumvent
> this limitation if they have strong, negative feelings against the
> prisoner. The most extreme form of isolation is the quiet cell where a
> prisoner finds himself in a stripped cell, with just a mattress on a
> cement block and a metal toilet and sink. He is allowed no personal
> property and the lights may be kept off at intervals or completely at
> the discretion of the staff. For regular isolation, prisoners are not
> kept in quiet cells. However, the prisoners are still locked up 24
> hours a day, with no personal property and with no smoking permitted.
>
> <sub><sup>[HOLE (FROM JUSTICE AND CORRECTIONS, 1978, BY NORMAN JOHNSTON AND LEONARD D SAVITZ - SEE NCJ-47922)](https://www.ojp.gov/ncjrs/virtual-library/abstracts/hole-justice-and-corrections-1978-norman-johnston-and-leonard-d)</sup></sub>